# Finding a number of occurrences of a certain character in tcsh

Tags: grep, filenames, tcsh

I am trying to find the number of certain types of files that have a '_' in the filename.

```
foreach txt ( 'ls *.txt')
set n=0
if(grep _ txt) then
@ n = n+1
endif
end
```

It doesn't work as my if statement isn't correct, but I'm not sure how to define saying if the txt file has a '_' within the filename then increment n by 1.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of files that have a `_` in them, or for each file, how many `_` it has?

Comment: The actual name of the file not what's within the file

Comment: So you want the number of files that have at least one `_`, or the number of  `_` in each filename?

Comment: The number of files that have a '_' within the filename, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to use the shell's globbing capabilities rather than using grep.

```
set n=0
foreach txt (*_*.txt)
    @ n++
end
```

The syntax for the "if grep" thing if you needed that for other reasons would be:

```
if ( { grep -q _ $var } ) then
  ...
endif
```

(`-q` tells grep to be quiet and not print out anything.)

Comment: Hi Matt, the first one of this is just what I was looking for. i find it hard to find any of this online, do you have a good resource place where I can read up on what you've just done for me?

Comment: For a start, just read through your shell's man page (skip the sections that you really don't care about), that will make you familiar with all the stuff it can do. Then it's more of a matter of trying things out and looking at existing scripts (your system is full of them, just poke around). (And I wouldn't try to learn csh/tcsh if you're just starting. ksh/bash are much more common these days, you'll find more things about them online.)

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of filenames that have a certain character use:

```
set n=`ls *.txt | fgrep -c _`
```

This will print only the filenames that have the character found and then count the number of entries returned.  In tcsh, you need to prefix assignments with `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` command in combination with `wc` to get the number of file with a `_` in the name:

```
set n=`find [path] -maxdepth 1 -name "*_*.txt" | wc -l`
```

Replace `[path]` with the directory you would like to search.